# CKEDITOR bidi buttons disabled

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, bidi

When adding the bidi plugin to the ckeditor I manage to add the rtl and trl buttons on the toolbar but they are disabled.

Does anyone know how to enable them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got custom `allowedContent` setting? If so, you need to add rules which will enable bidi buttons. For example:

```
config.allowedContent = yourCrrentRules +
    '; h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 table ul ol blockquote div tr p div li td[dir]';
```

Comment: thanx that worked but all my other toolbar buttons now dissappeared.. only the bidi ones are shown

Comment: This is my code: @Reinmar

`instance = CKEDITOR.replace('richtext-editor', {
            toolbar: [
                { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyRight','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'] }
            ],
            enterMode: Number(2),
            allowedContent: 'h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 table ul ol blockquote div tr p div li td[dir]',
            removePlugins : 'magicline'
        });`

Comment: Never mind i set allowedContent: true and then it all worked again. Thank you!!

Comment: Setting `allowedContent` to `true` should be the last resort. I assumed that you had some ACF settings, but they were to strict for bidi, so I meant that you can extend those settings, not override by what I showed.

Comment: I didnt have any ACF configured yet. what would you suggest instead then?

Answer (score 0):

I addition to Reinmar, There could be another reason. If you disabled div or p elements in the editor, it will also cause this issue.

E.g. It will be disabled once you set `enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` to force the enter behavior to 'br'